# "Fix your application" Warning from glassfish when deploying war

Tags: java, eclipse, jax-ws, glassfish-3

I get this annoying warning and basicly error from glassfish (3.1):

```
"http://localhost:4848/management/domain/applications/application/websrvice-test-1.0" created successfully. WARNING: Command _deploy did not complete successfully on server instance TodoAppWBConnection: remote failure: Failed to load the application on instance TodoAppWBConnection. The application will not run properly. Please fix your application and redeploy.
```

repeats twice...

This is the code I added today, yesterday the .war deploying went well, today I added this bit of code and now it errors.

```
@WebMethod
public @WebResult(name="TaskUpdated")boolean updateTaskWithId(@WebParam(name="Username")String username,@WebParam(name="Id")String id,@WebParam(name="category")String category,@WebParam(name="completion_dtm")Date completion_dtm,@WebParam(name="desc")String desc,@WebParam(name="duedate")Date duedate,@WebParam(name="notification_duedate")String notification_duedate,@WebParam(name="notification_one")String notification_one,@WebParam(name="notification_two")String notification_two,@WebParam(name="priority")int priority,@WebParam(name="reminder_one")Date reminder_one,@WebParam(name="reminder_two")Date reminder_two,@WebParam(name="title")String title,@WebParam(name="timestamp")Date timestamp)
{
    //String sql = "REPLACE INTO tasks VALUES('" + category + "','" + completion_dtm + "','" + desc + "','" + duedate + "','" + notification_duedate + "','" + notification_one + "','" + notification_two + "'," + priority + ",'" + reminder_one + "','" + reminder_two + "','" + timestamp + "','" + title + "','" + username + "','" + id + "')";
    String sql = "UPDATE tasks VALUES('" + category + "','" + completion_dtm + "','" + desc + "','" + duedate + "','" + notification_duedate + "','" + notification_one + "','" + notification_two + "'," + priority + ",'" + reminder_one + "','" + reminder_two + "','" + timestamp + "','" + title + "','" + username + "','" + id + "') WHERE id = '"+ id + "'";
    Connection connection = getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps;
    try 
    {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception preperationError)
    {
        //System.out.println(preperationError);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        closeConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

I'm using eclipse with Maven plugin, I clean my project and install it to generate the war file. Then deploy it on a Standalone instance I made in glassfish. Yesterday it was working fine until I added the pice of code above. Any help? Thanks in advance. Just tell me if I should post more information.

Again, thanks!

EDIT: There's an insane amount of text, cant past it all, but they all basicly start with

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.glassfish.webservices.WSServletContextListener java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.glassfish.webservices.WSServletContextListener at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:921) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901) at
```

EDIT2:

```
288 SEVERE  Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: or... (details)   javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin  Feb 27, 2012 14:20:19.179   _ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-4;
287 SEVERE  Exception while loading the app(details)    javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server   Feb 27, 2012 14:20:19.166   _ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-4;
286 SEVERE  Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method java.lang.Exceptio... (details)   javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin  Feb 27, 2012 14:20:19.148   _ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-4;
285 WARNING java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleExcepti... (details)   javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web    Feb 27, 2012 14:20:19.148   _ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-4;
284 SEVERE  ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentExc... (details)    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase  Feb 27, 2012 14:20:19.145   _ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-4;
283 INFO    WS-TX Services successfully started.(details)
```

EDIT3:
Tried installing gf 3.0.1 in a different port with different updates installed from the update tool, it deploys seccessfully but it doesnt generate a WSDL link or file, O I cant use it anyway...

EDIT4:
Updating gf from 3.0.1 to 3.1 (official) broke it, doing a manual uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Is there something more in the server.log? Any Exceptions thrown?

Comment: Check the log. More details there.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Provided

Comment: If you take the new code out, does it go back to a working state?  And I would guess there's still more in the logs.  Glassfish tends to log a lot of side effects for errors like this which can be misleading.  You need to make sure you start reading the errors from the beginning and generally ignore the later errors.

Comment: @Jim will make a habit of it, and no, I cut-pasted the code out into textedit and it still doesnt deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found problem. I was using java.sql.Date which glassfish cound not understand, now I need to format any strings like it would have been a date, more work!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when there was no database connection to the SQL server db. I created a connection pool and JNDI reference and was able to deploy successfully. 
The error message was highly misleading. My web server was glassfish 3.1